# Report Viewer Using C# and Access Database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, report, reportviewer

I want to retrieve some data in a certain table in database access but when every time i am retrieving data from the database it will only give me a blank data inside of it. to make it more detailed here's my code

```
private void simpleButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboSearch.Text == "ALL")
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\\MotoFix.mdb");

                OleDbCommand Com = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                Con.Open();
                Com.Connection = Con;

                if (true)
                {
                    Com.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT prodCode as [Code], prodName as [Name], prodDescription as [Description], prodBrand as [Brand], prodSRP as [Product Price], sCategory as [Category] FROM Product");
                    adapter.SelectCommand = Com;
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }

                this.productBindingSource.DataSource = dt; 
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); 
                Con.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't do this: `throw ex;` This is removing valuable information. If you want to throw the exception again, use `throw;` only or just omit the catch block alltogether.

Comment: It's still the same, it's still doesn't show any records :D

Comment: Did you debug it? What is inside your data table? Did your SQL produce data?

Comment: yes! The name of my Table is Product and it have many values inside :)

Comment: How are `this.productBindingSource.DataSource = dt;` and                 `this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();` connected? Do you have any report that works, or is it your first?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have reports which are working. Can you give me some ? :(